# How to Solve ERROR Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `style` of type `array` supplied to `Row`, expected `object` (react-native-table-component)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-table-component

Here i'm working on a react-native-table-compornent.
when i try to run my project, and display my data in table (react native),
i get this type of error **( ERROR  Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `textStyle` of type `array` supplied to `Cell`, expected `object`.)** on my project;

how can solve this error warning?
where is the problem in my codes? i am sharing here in below my codes.

when i excute this code, i can able to view those data in table but besides i also get this error warning in my project, so i want to solve this Warning.
anyone can help me how to fix this error or where i should do what in my project?

i appreciate your helping, thankyou in advance!

Here i am sharing my codes, i have use in vs code(react native):

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { Table, Row } from "react-native-table-component";

const TT = () => {
  const th = ["Name", "Age", "Gmail", "Occupation"];
  const widthArr = [150, 150, 150, 150];
  const td = [
    ["John", 32, "john01@gmail.com", "Doctor"],
    ["Paul", 39, "poul09@gmail.com", "Teacher"],
    ["Rokey", 45, "rokey03@gmail.com", "Engineer"]
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        <View>
          <Table
            style={{ marginTop: 12, marginLeft: 12 }}
            borderStyle={{ borderColor: "#FAEBD7", borderWidth: 1 }}
          >
            <Row
              data={th}
              widthArr={widthArr}
              style={styles.header}
              textStyle={styles.headerText}
            />
          </Table>
          <ScrollView style={styles.dataWrapper}>
            <Table
              style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}
              borderStyle={{ borderColor: "#FAEBD7", borderWidth: 1 }}
            >
              {td?.map((rowData, index) => (
                <Row
                  key={index}
                  data={rowData}
                  widthArr={widthArr}
                  style={[
                    styles.row,
                    index % 2 && { backgroundColor: "#212733" }
                  ]}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </Table>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
export default TT;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 18,
    backgroundColor: "#212732"
  },
  header: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#2F4F4F"
  },
  headerText: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "400",
    color: "white"
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "300",
    color: "#fefefe"
  },
  dataWrapper: {
    marginTop: -1
  },
  row: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#2c3445"
  }
});
```

output of error:
[image]

[image]

Comment: is there have any solution of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-native-table-component isn't being maintained by its original developer. Warnings like this are covered in the repo's issues section, and there are great forks that fix some errors.

So in my case i choose to use different library which is react native paper;
libraries: npm i react-native-paper

using dataTable i finished my project. for more information https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/data-table.html